# Wait in real time for new entries in SQL Database in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am developping a script in PowerShell which is running on a server hosting a database. The script is supposed to check in real time the evolution of a table in the database, meaning that as soon as it detects a new entry in the table it is watching, it will send me an email with the new entry in this table.

The script I did is not really checking in real-time. It is always running while the server is on, and every minutes, it checks for new entries in the database and send an email if needed.

```
while ($True) {
    ### Do the checking ###
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

I don't think the way I did it is very clean and smart, so my question is: Is there any way to wait "in real time" for new entries in a SQL database table ?

By real time, I mean as soon as a new line is added to the table, my script detects it, and not after waiting some amount of time and doing the checking.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres and Oracle have features to send messages to the client. Maybe those are available through PowerShell as well

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014, but I was wondering if there was any way to "listen" to a database using PowerShell

Comment: How about going with SQL's Transaction-Notifications?

Comment: That seems to be exaclty what I am looking for @Akaino thank you so much

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!